# What is best for performance with array?

Tags: arrays, angular

I have a component that displays a list. From an observable, I can received added item or the new array. What is the best on performance perspective?

```ts
myArray=[];
$myArray.subsscribe(d=>this.myArray=d)
```

```ts
myArray=[];
$myArrayJustNewItem.subsscribe(d=>this.myArray.push(d))
```

```html
<span *ngFor='item of myArray'>{{item}}</span>
```

What I understood, is whatever solution, the view will be re-render entirely? Or should I use index?

Comment: No, the view won't be re-rendered. Depending on your item tracking in your `*ngFor`, it could ony append a new item to the view, instead of redrawing it entirely.

Answer (score -1):

There are two places which may be used in a different way

1. You don't have to `.subscribe()` you can always use `async pipe`. In this case you avoid creating a new variable and direct subscription to an Observable, which obviously a better solution.

   ```
   myArray$: Observable<any[]>; // or any other type

   <div *ngFor="let item of (myArray$ | async)">{{ item }}</div>
   ```
2. If you want to add new item to an existing array, which renders inside `*ngFor`, you should do it like this: (actually create a new Array instance with the same or updated content).
   Pushing a new item to an existing array, probably should be done on a service or even on a server side, so your component always gets a new array instance and won't need to manually add it, so re-render only happens when new data comes to Observable.

   ```
   myArray: Array<any> = [1,2,3,4];

   addItemToArray(item: number): void {
      this.myArray = [...this.myArray, item];
   }


   <div *ngFor="let item of myArray">{{ item }}</div>
   ```

*UPDATE: added descriptions and advices for a performance perspective*

Comment: thanks for your answer, but it doesn't answer my question. What the best on performance perspective

Comment: My question is about adding a new item, not changing the all array.